# Perl, JSON, and Discord Emoji

Tags: json, perl, discord

I have a very simple `DiscordBOT` doing some administrative tasks.
One of the features is (or should be) our "`emoji based polls`". We make a post, with emojis listing the options complete with arrows pointing down to the right "reaction" below the comment.

The idea was to make the bot (on command) duplicate the given reactions to the post, so that the admin can remove his/her reactions, and actually slap a  reaction to the option they'd like to vote fore.

Everything works fine... until the error of:

```
 {"code": 10014, "message": "Unknown Emoji"}
```

The perl script, by the powers of LWP, **reads** the reactions from the test post as "`\ud83d\ude0f`", but putting them back "as is" just doesn't work.

Putting the same reaction back as "`\x{1F60F}`" instead works fine! (source: https://codepoints.net/U+1F60F?lang=en )

I don't mind, except ... how do I convert all those `\u-based emojis to \x-based ones? =P`
After some heavy googling and trial-and-error I've tried things such as "decode_json/encode_json" etc, but I can't seem to be able to make it work. I'm thinking I must missing something small and "obvious"...

Thanks for any assist!

Also open for other "outside the box" ideas if they solve the problem! =P

Comment: You are effectively asking us to debug code without showing us the code. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show how you parse the JSON that contains those sequences, but whatever JSON parser you are using appears to be buggy. Use some other parser such as [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON::XS) instead.

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );
use utf8;
use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";

use Encode   qw( encode_utf8 );
use JSON::XS qw( decode_json );

{
   # If you get decoded JSON.
   my $json_text = '{ "foo": "\ud83d\ude0f" }';
   my $data = JSON::XS->new->decode($json_text);
   say $data->{foo};
   say $data->{foo} eq "\x{1F60F}" ? "match" : "no match";
}

{
   # If you get JSON encoded using UTF-8.
   my $json_utf8 = encode_utf8('{ "foo": "\ud83d\ude0f" }');
   my $data = decode_json($json_utf8);
   say $data->{foo};
   say $data->{foo} eq "\x{1F60F}" ? "match" : "no match";
}
```

Output:

```
match

match
```

Answer (score 2):

U+d83d and U+de0f are the high and low surrogate pair equating to character U+1F60F. Surrogate pairs are used in the UTF-16 encodings to encode code points higher than U+FFFF. The formula to convert the surrogate pair to a code point is

```
<code point> = (<high surrogate> - D800) * 400 + (<low surrogate> - DC00) + 10000
```

All numbers are in hexadecimal.

See [The Surrogate Pair Calculator](http://www.russellcottrell.com/greek/utilities/SurrogatePairCalculator.htm#info) for more information.

This should really be being done by your encode/decode library.